# How can I dynamically schedule emails with APScheduler, Flask and Heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, flask-restful, apscheduler

I have a Flask API (Flask RESTFull) app on Heroku, and I want to extend its capabilities by adding dynamic email scheduling. The users can enable email notifications for their items, and when they do it, I send a post request for each user/item. How I currently coded it:

- I have a route for scheduling emails: URL/emailNotifications
- I send a POST request with the date I need to trigger
- I start a BackgroundScheduler for each user item on the front-end

`app.py` file where I have my POST request defined

```
def post(self):
  parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    
  parser.add_argument("email")
  parser.add_argument("trigger_date")
  parser.add_argument("job_id")
  args = parser.parse_args()
  try:
    scheduleEmailNoti(args['email'], args['trigger_date'], args['job_id'])
    return "Email notification scheduled",201
  except Exception as e:
    return f"Error during posting the scheduled email notification, {e}", 404
```

`jobs.py` file

```
# Not sure which one to use :S
# from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
# sched = BlockingScheduler()
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)

# Scheduling an email notification
def scheduleEmailNoti(email, trigger_date, job_id):
    # sendEmailNotification() function sends the email with Gmail
    sched.add_job(lambda: sendEmailNotification(email,trigger_date),'date', run_date=trigger_date, id=job_id)
    sched.start()
```

`Procfile`

```
web: gunicorn app:app
clock: python jobs.py
```

Then after this app boots up in Heroku I run this command

`heroku ps:scale clock=1`

My problem is that if I want to schedule 3 email alerts (3 POST request) for the 3 items the user got, only one gets created and I am not sure why. On localhost I can hit my endpoint a 1000 times, and that many jobs gets created. (I have a GET request also, which just returns all the job ID's in the queue)

Am I doing this right?